# Make my own bootstrap btn class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I would like to use `less` to make my own button class instead of having to add `btn btn-large btn-red` etc to all the elements.

How is this done with less? The various things I have tried just make the less file not parse at all.

Something like:

```
.my-button {
    .btn;
    .btn-large;
}
```

I seem to have this problem with various styles I try and customise and combine to new classes.

Comment: this should work. What are you using to compile your .less? I have had issues with some compilers.

Comment: I am using [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) when in debug mode which fails. I use some php version of something similar to cache production. From what I remember that also breaks but I will test again.

Comment: I assume you are adding .my-button AFTER the other two clases? To compile I use CodeKit (mac only) which works fairly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old thread, but there is a better way to do this today, so I'd like to leave it documented for others.

LESS 1.5 introduced reference imports, so today you can just reference the entire bootstrap source and use whatever you want without any output from bootstrap itself.

```
@import (reference) 'less/bootstrap.less';

.my-button {
    .btn;
    .btn-lg;
}
```

Only ".my-button" will be output, so you can still reference bootstrap from a CDN and have your CSS with only your customization.

Answer (score 0):

I double checked your code by adding

```
.my-button {
.btn;
.btn-large;
}
```

to my buttons.less file, compiled with less, and uploaded the new CSS file. Then I added a test link

```
<a class="my-button" href="#">test button</a>
```

Everything looked good. I know it's not necessarily a good idea to edit the default bootstrap less files directly but it helps rule out some problems quickly.

How are you customising your settings in less?

Answer (score 0):

You do the definition of the custom button class just as it should be. So, here some hints where the error could be:

- the bootstrap classes are compiled after the custom class. Thus, check your less import hierarchy.
- the bootstrap class definitions are not part of your less universum, i.e., they are nowhere imported to the main less file that you pass to the less compiler as argument.

For the second step, below a short summary how it could be setup.

styles.less (this is your main file).

```
// bootstrap base imports (v2.2.2)
@import "plugins/bootstrap/reset.less";
@import "plugins/bootstrap/variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc
@import "plugins/bootstrap/mixins.less";
// [...]

@import "layouts.less";
```

note that the [...] stands for all the other bootstrap imports (see main bootstrap less file at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less).

And your `layouts.less` defines your customized button class as you already wrote:

```
.my-button {
    .btn;
    .btn-large;
}
```

In your less compiler, you would end up to execute

```
lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

Note also that you will need the actual less files of bootstrap in the folder `plugins/bootstrap/`.

Hope this helps.